# Mimic background-size:cover with an img in a div with CSS only

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is this possible? The code below copies half of the behaviour, the image will always cover the `div`. The problem is that it'll always be cropped in both axis if the `div` is smaller than `img`'s dimensions.

Adding a `max-width: 100%` or `max-height: 100%` to the `img` causes the image to distort. Is there any way to solve this without using JavaScript/`background-img`.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.tall {
  height: 400px;
}

div.wide {
  width: 400px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

img.tallCat {
  max-width: 100%;
}

img.wideCat {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Expected output:
<div style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOwb.jpg);background-size:cover;">
</div>

Actual output:
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOwb.jpg">
</div>

Actual output with max-width:
<div class="tall">
  <img class="tallCat" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOwb.jpg">
</div>

Actual output with max-height:
<div class="wide">
  <img class="wideCat" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCOwb.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `object-fit` parameter which does what you want (you can set it to `cover` or  `contain`), but it isn't supported by IE/Edge yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=fit

Addition: Look at the settings in this snippet (original images size provided inside the image tag, CSS rules for image having `width: 100%`):

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

img.x {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
img.y {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/fa0" width="500" height="200" class="x">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200/fa0" width="500" height="200" class="y">
</div>
```

Comment: Nevermind, you apply `object-fit` to the `img`, with a supplied width/height. Thanks.

Comment: I added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

Hide the image (`visibility:hidden` or `opacity:0`) and apply it to the div as a background image in your markup. Of course, if you do this, it begs the question as to why you need the img element at all.

Comment: Aye I'm specifically trying to avoid using an inline style, while having a dynamic background image.

Comment: @Eamonn - why are you trying to avoid inline style? I use `background-image` in lots of places for this exact purpose.

Comment: Because they're smelly and I don't like them. I want to be able to apply properties and other things to an actual img tag, so I ideally want to build it  as `<div><img src='x.jpg'></div>`.

Comment: @Eamonn - that's illogical. you won't use the property you want just because you believe it's bad practice. Hint: it's nod bad practice when it's what you need.

Comment: I want to know if it's possible, the reason why is secondary.

Comment: @Eamonn - the reason why people ask questions is **never** secondary.